# Angularjs : How do a function scope() in angularjs/javascript works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm new in java script world and just learn **AngularJS**. I have a question about the `scope()` function, by the way i know how a scope works in **JavaScript** what bothering me is the `scope()` function.

I saw several codes that they attach it into an element in **jQuery**. I just wonder what does that function do to an element and when should i use that function. I don't see any documentation about that function in **JavaScript** so i hope someone can explained it to me here.

Comment: The `scope()` function is documented in [AngularJS angular.element API Reference -- jQuery/jqLite Extras](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#jquery-jqlite-extras). Best only used for debugging purposes.

Comment: man thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to access the angular scope that an element exists in from outside of angular.

It is rarely needed and often is used as a bad practice by people that aren't comfortable working within angular itself.

As a beginner there are far more important things to learn about

Comment: ohh that's why i dont see any of it talking in the internet, thanks mate :)

Comment: *As a beginner there are far more important things to learn about* e.g. angular2 or react :)